# How to hide internal testing method from client without breaking change

Tags: java, android, architecture

Originally I have one class with all methods. (It is not right syntax but should be enough to demonstrate what I want to do)

```
class A {
  public static class1
  public static method1
  public static var1
  ...
  public testmethod2
  public testvar2
  ...
}
```

In this case I do

```
import static com.example.A.class1;
import static com.example.A.method1;
```

in other class to import.

However I want to hide testMethods from client. So I restructure the code a bit to make it use different version of class A (in different files) based on buildType

```
class A_shared {
  public static class1
  public static method1
  public static var1
  ...
}
```

In Debug:

```
class A extends A_shared {
  public testmethod2
  public testvar2
  ...
}
```

In Release:

```
class A extends A_shared {

}
```

It works great. People can still use class A without noticing any change.
But for `class1` I have to import A_shared instead of A while for static method and variable I can still use A to import.

```
import static com.example.A_shared.class1;
import static com.example.A.method1;
```

Am I missing something?
Is it possible in Java / Android to be able to import class1 from A after I restructure the code so I will not break anything at client side?

If it is not possible, then...
1. Is there a better way to implement the restructure in order to hide specific method (variable) based on different type of build / flavor while not breaking anything on client side?
2. I am curious why only the class1 has to be imported with superclass while other static methods and vars don't.

Thanks for any thought.

**UPDATE 2018/8/9:**
I should elaborate more of our use case.
I am providing a library for our Android application developer to include in gradle dependency.

There are two builds of the app.
In debug build he will include debug version of the library which has all the testing methods and variables so he can show the internal state of the app.
In release build (it goes up to play store) he uses release version of library which has all testing things stripped away.

For some testing methods we run it for internal benchmarking to integrate test our library. They do not run in production version of the app. The usage for these testing methods and variables are for both monitoring and benchmarking.

Our client uses the release version of the library (SDK) in their own app.

Comment: default method for interface is out of question since it only supported beyond api level 24.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I would make the methods/members `protected` to indicate that they are *not* part of the class's public API, but would leave them with/in the same class for your and others' benefit as documentation on the designed behaviour of the class. But this make break clients that are (improperly?) using these methods?

Note that the convention for most is that the unit tests are under `src/test/java/package/` for code in `src/main/java/package/`, so *if* you have any test methods in the main class, they should be very specific hooks for inspection and use by only the test classes, and probably avoided if possible.

Extending a class to add testability is probably a bad idea - makes the complexity of the code increase and adds to the class size unnecessarily.

Another question is the purpose of these test methods - are they just for unit testing? Or for testing in a production(or production-like) environment? I.e. are they part of the operation and monitoring of the application? or solely for build-time testing?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. 
Client shouldn't use these method as it is not documented so we don't care breaking them if they improperly use these testing methods.
For other questions I've updated the question. Let me know if it is still not clear for you. Thanks!

Comment: Presuming on the use of Gradle, see here: https://thoughtfulsoftware.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/integration-testing-a-gradle-application/ - same philosophy as unit testing applies, put test code under src/intTest/pkg etc.